# Django form not saving to database via ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to add my form to the database using the ModelForm but it's not going through or even printing the form in the view, i have also tried doing each field alone in the view via cleaned data still nothing inserted in the database

my view.py

```
def index(request):
    component = Component.objects.all()
    form = ComponentModelForm()
    if request == 'POST':
        form = ComponentModelForm(request.POST)
        print(form)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/maintenance')  
        else:
            form = ComponentModelForm()              
    context = {
        'components': component,
        'form':ComponentModelForm(),
    }
    return render(request, 'maintenance/index.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Component(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    note = models.TextField()
    parent = TreeForeignKey("self", verbose_name=(
        "Parent Component"), blank=True, null=True, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}, {self.name}"
```

forms.py

```
class ComponentModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Component
        fields = ("name",
                  "manufacturer",
                  "model",
                  "serial_number",
                  "price",
                  "note",
                  "parent",)
```

the template:

```
   <div>
         <form method='POST' action=''>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <input type="submit" value='Create'/>
         </form>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
If request.method == 'POST'
```

Instead of:

```
If request == 'POST'
```